# Lua class instance with nested tables

Tags: class, oop, lua, nested, lua-table

Simple Lua game with simple class like so:

```
creature = class({ 
name = "MONSTER BADDY!",

stats = { power = 10, agility = 10, endurance = 10, filters = {} },

other_things = ...
})

creatureA = creature.new()

creatureB = creature.new()

creatureA.name = "Frank"

creatureB.name = "Zappa"

creatureA.stats.agility = 20

creatureB.stats.power = 12
```

-- blah blah blah

Non table values are individual to each instance, but table values are
shared among all instances and if I modify a stats.X value in one instance,
all other instances see the same stats table.

Q1: Is my OO implementation flawed? I tried LOOP and the same result occured,
is there a fundamental flaw in my logic?

Q2: How would you have each instance of creature have it's own stats table (and sub tables)?

PS. I cannot flatten my class table as it's a bit more complicated than the example and other parts of the code are simplified with this nested table implementation.

Comment: Also, you don't need the brackets in the function call to class. class { } == class({ }).

Answer (score 3):

It works like that because class instances have the class table set as `__index` in their metatable ( well, most implementations work that way )
So if you access `creatureA.stats` ( and it can't find `stats` on `creatureA`, thus falls to `__index` ) it returns `creature.stats`.
Maybe you should read up on [Lua 5.1 Reference Manual: Metatables](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8)

You won't be able to declare per-instance variables in the class's table constructor ( unless you deep copy everything from the class table to the instance, which would be quite expensive )

You'll have to do it in whatever initializer function your class implementation uses:

```
creature = class
{
     __init = function(self, ...)
         self.stats = {power = 10, agility = 10, endurance = 10, filters = {}}
     end,
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`class` is not a standard function in Lua.  You don't say if you've borrowed it from Roberto, rolled your own, or what.  But my guess is that you want to change the `new` method so that it does a **deep copy** of the prototype instead of a shallow copy:

```
function deep_copy(v)
  if type(v) == 'table' then
    local u = { }
    for k, v in pairs(v) do
      u[k] = v
    end
    setmetatable(u, getmetatable(v))
    return u
  else
    return v
  end
end
```

(Alert: I haven't tried to compile this code, let alone run it.)

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new `creature` you could always create a new `stats` table for it if you don't want it to be shared.

```
creature = class({ 
    name = "MONSTER BADDY!",
    stats = stats.new({ power = 10, agility = 10, endurance = 10, filters = {} }),
    other_things = ...
})
```

Power, agility etc. would be passed as arguments in the constructor for `stats`.

Answer (score 0):

That function of yours called  **class**  looks suspicious. I go would for simplest possible code. Here is a monster class file. Nothing fancy and some people would say it lacks some fluff but at least I can read the code myself next week too.

```
-- Class object

monster = {}
monster.__index = monster

-- Class methods

function monster.new(name)
    local o = {}
    o.name = name
    o.stats = {power = 10, agility = 10, endurance = 10, filters = {}}
    setmetatable(o, monster)
    return o
end

function monster:shout()
    print('Aaaaaaa! My name is ' .. self.name .. '!')
end
```

And here is the output:

```
> lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require 'monster'
> m = monster.new('Katla')
> m:shout()
Aaaaaaa! My name is Katla!
```